# Simple Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: python

import random

def play():

```
options=['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
user = input("What's your choice? 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors\n")
computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])
if user == computer:
    return 'It\'s a tie!'
if is_win(user, computer):
    return 'You won'
else:
    return("You lost! Better luck next time!")
```

def is_win(player, opponent):

```
if (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponent == 'p') or (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r'):
    return True
```

def script():

```
restart = input("Would you like play again?")
if restart == "yes" or restart == True:
    play()
if restart == "no" or restart == "n":
    print("Thanks for playing!")
```

print(play())

script()

Output:

What's your choice? 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors

r

You lost! Better luck next time!
Would you like play again?
yes

What's your choice? 'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors

p

williamchildress@Wills-MacBook-Pro-M1 RPS %

Game is supposed to repeat with result after next input "p"

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Edit the question and post the full code, actual output, and expected output as plain text.

Comment: There is no loop in the code in the image

Comment: The `script()` function don't print the result when it calls `play()`. Change `play()` to `print(play())`, just like you do before calling `script()`

Comment: Welcome to SO - it's very important that your Question is accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it can be searched, copy-and-pasted, and discovered by the community!

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding the play() function inside of script(), try using a while loop. You're printing out play() at the end of your code, and then you're calling the play() function again in script() but not printing anything to console. Returning the value of a function doesn't print it out unless you say print().